# Downgrade jpype to 0.6.3

Tags: python, jdbc, jpype, jaydebeapi

I am currently trying to establish a jdbc connection.
I am using:

```
jaydebeapi version - 1.1.1
```

Because of some incompatibility issues, I'm trying to downgrade from jpype version - 0.7.2 to version 0.6.3 with this command :

```
pip install JPype1==0.6.3 --force-reinstall
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/user/venv/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5271s9v5/JPype1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5271s9v5/JPype1/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-lnqyidc1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/venv/include/site/python3.8/JPype1

 gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your c++ compiler is broken/not installed. For 0.6.3 there are no precompiled binaries, so you have to compile it yourself (with the automated aid of pip).

Eventually you should ask the jaydebeapi maintainers to solve this incompatibility issue to have a future proof and safe solution. For recent jpype version you do not have to compile yourself, if you use Windows, Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately JPype has introduced some backwards incompatible changes in the last couple of releases that broke compatibility to JayDeBeApi.

In the meantime JayDeBeApi>=1.2.0 has been released. This version supports the newer JPype1 versions. Please upgrade

```
pip install --upgrade JayDeBeApi JPype1
```